# Eigenvalues with a matrix close to a set of coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a 2x2 matrix {(-2,6),(-3, 7)} (those are row vectors)

Note that the eigenvalues of A are {1,4} . Let v = (3, 2) T and w =

$$w=\frac{\sqrt2}{\left\|A^{163}v\right\|}A^{163}v$$

Is w closer to (1, 1) T or (2, 1) T?

T is a transpose.

How do I go about solving this? Would I do A * lambda(Id) where lambda are the two eigenvalues given? thanks

Comment: What is "T" in your question??

Comment: Sorry that's a transpose symbol.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think it means transpose.

Comment: @mfl Yes, it seems to be so. Thanks....:)

Comment: How does $A^{163}$ act on its eigenvectors?

Comment: I'm really not sure what the complicated equation is doing.

Answer (score 1):

What have that

$$\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 6\\ -3 & 7\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1  \\  1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4  \\  4\end{pmatrix}=4\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 6\\ -3 & 7\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2  \\  1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2  \\  1\end{pmatrix}$$

Now,

$$\begin{pmatrix}3  \\  2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1  \\  1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}2  \\  1\end{pmatrix}$$ from where

$$A^{163}\begin{pmatrix}3  \\  2\end{pmatrix}=A^{163}\begin{pmatrix}1  \\  1\end{pmatrix}+A^{163}\begin{pmatrix}2  \\  1\end{pmatrix}=4^{163}\begin{pmatrix}1  \\  1\end{pmatrix}+1^{163}\begin{pmatrix}2  \\  1\end{pmatrix}$$

So, the vector we have got is $(4^{163}+2,4^{163}+1).$ Now we make it unit. That is, we will compute $$\dfrac{A^{163}v}{\|A^{163}v\|}.$$ It is:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(4^{163}+2)^2+(4^{163}+1)^2}}(4^{163}+2,4^{163}+1) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\cdot 4^{163}}(4^{163}+2,4^{163}+1)\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1).$$ Finally,

$$w\approx \sqrt{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)=(1,1).$$

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to conclude from that. It just seems that i get a multiple of the vector I multiplied by. The same thing happens with the other vector as well. I know the correct answer is (1,1)T I just need to understand why.

Comment: I have misread the question. Now I have given the correct hint.

Comment: I'm still not following what I'm supposed to do. To get (3,2) i see you added the results of multiplying the matrix by each of the two vectors given. But (3,2) is also given as V. I'm not even sure what's going on in the last line or what I'm supposed to conclude from it.

Comment: $\dfrac{A^{163}v}{\|A^{163}v\|}$ is a unit vector. So, make $4^{163}\begin{pmatrix}1  \\  1\end{pmatrix}+1^{163}\begin{pmatrix}2  \\  1\end{pmatrix}$ and multiply it by $\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: How does 4^163(1,1)+1^163(2,1) * \sqrt(2) get anywhere near (1,1)?

Comment: The vector is $(4^{163}+2,4^{163}).$ So, we have $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(4^{163}+2)^2+(4^{163}})^2}(4^{163}+2,4^{163}) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\cdot 4^{163}}(4^{163}+2,4^{163})\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1).$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48048/discussion-between-frillybob-and-mfl).